# iOS purchase server validation: multiple in_app purchases

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I'm new to iOS purchases flow but I have a general understanding of it. I've faced with purchase validation response which is confusing me. The response looks like this:

```
 "in_app": [
        {
            "quantity": "1",
            "product_id": "****.1year",
            "transaction_id": "350000229416748",
            "original_transaction_id": "350000229416748",
            "purchase_date": "2017-06-12 21:31:03 Etc/GMT",
            "purchase_date_ms": "1497303063000",
            "purchase_date_pst": "2017-06-12 14:31:03 America/Los_Angeles",
            "original_purchase_date": "2017-06-12 21:31:03 Etc/GMT",
            "original_purchase_date_ms": "1497303063000",
            "original_purchase_date_pst": "2017-06-12 14:31:03 America/Los_Angeles",
            "is_trial_period": "false"
        },
        {
            "quantity": "1",
            "product_id": "****.1year",
            "transaction_id": "350000229419682",
            "original_transaction_id": "350000229419682",
            "purchase_date": "2017-06-12 21:54:23 Etc/GMT",
            "purchase_date_ms": "1497304463000",
            "purchase_date_pst": "2017-06-12 14:54:23 America/Los_Angeles",
            "original_purchase_date": "2017-06-12 21:54:23 Etc/GMT",
            "original_purchase_date_ms": "1497304463000",
            "original_purchase_date_pst": "2017-06-12 14:54:23 America/Los_Angeles",
            "is_trial_period": "false"
        }
```

On receipt validation I can see two different purchases (because of different original transaction ids) with a same product id (purchase is valid for 1 year) and different purchase dates (which are pretty close).
So should I tread it as a user did a purchase for two times and his general period of valid purchase should be like "2017-06-12 21:31:03" + 2 years? Is it even possible? Or my understanding of it is completly wrong?

Comment: One could be a renewal or it could be a second purchase; In the sandbox renewals happen at an accelerated rate so you can test.  Eventually renewal stops and you can purchase again; this allows you to simulate a cancel and re-subscribe.  You should check the expiration in the `latest_receipt` field after you validate the receipt.

Comment: But if a first one was bought on 2017-06-12 21:31:03 so the renewing should take place on 2018-06-12 21:31:03 (purchase with 1 year period)?

Comment: Not in the sandbox.  As I said, renewals in the sandbox happen much faster; every few minutes.  Otherwise it would take you years to test your app :)

Comment: Yes, but this is a real purchase because I'm receiving it from https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt. If I'm trying to do it via  https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt I'm getting 21008 status code

Comment: What type of products are these?

Comment: If you mean non-consumable, consumable etc. then I'm not sure... Sorry, but I'm only improving a backend and I have no experience with iOS purchases. How can I check that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172162/discussion-between-paulw11-and-roman-borovets).